# Разбить пользователей на возрастные группы

Tags: sql-server

Помогите составить запрос на разделение пользователей на возрастные группы.
Например на группы 18<, 18-25, 26-35, 36-45, >45

---

Таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE Fiz_person
( 
    id_client            integer IDENTITY(1,1),
    Surname              varchar(20)  NOT NULL ,
    Name                 varchar(20)  NOT NULL ,
    LastName             varchar(20)  NOT NULL ,
    Birth_date           datetime  NOT NULL ,
)
```

Comment: проблема то в чем у вас, в определении возраста, или разбиении его на группы?

Comment: Разбить выборку на возрастные группы

Comment: используйте оператор `case`: `case when age < 18 then 1 when age < 25 then 2 ... end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за инормацию, решил эту проблему вот так:
добавил новый столбец с возрастом:

```
ALTER TABLE Fiz_person ADD Age AS (YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(Birth_Date))
```

Потом сделал запросы как и подсказали с CASE'ом

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN  Age < 18 THEN 1 END) AS '<18', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN  Age > 19 AND Age < 25  THEN 1 END) AS '19-25', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN  Age > 26 AND Age < 39  THEN 1 END) AS '26-39', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN  Age > 40 AND Age < 65  THEN 1 END) AS '40-65', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN  Age > 65 THEN 1 END) '>65'
FROM Fiz_person
```